# ClassFormatError using JMockit with EMMA

Tags: jmockit, emma

I am trying to use EMMA to measure coverage of some JUnit tests that use JMockit. But when I try to run the JMockit tests after instrumenting with EMMA, about a quarter of the tests fail with the following error:

```
com.logstorage.engine.sensor.SensorManagerTest.setUpBeforeClass(SensorManagerTest.java:98)
    java.lang.ClassFormatError
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:150)
    at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:152)
    at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:139)
    at mockit.internal.RedefinitionEngine.redefineMethods(RedefinitionEngine.java:73)
    at mockit.Mockit.setUpMock(Mockit.java:235)
    at com.myapp.MyTest.setUpBeforeClass(MyTest.java:98)
```

I can't see any pattern as to which tests fail and which don't. I guess this is just a bug in JMockit, but does anybody know a workaround?

I found a very similar question called "Getting ClassFormatError with EMMA?" but the solution doesn't work for me (I'm not using any reentrant=true mock methods). Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It must be the alignment of the Moon. With nothing changed I wasn't getting this error two days ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been running into the same problem - this seems to have fixed it for me and hopefully will help anybody else as well.

If you're running this through `ant`, make sure you don't have `vars` in your `javac` target's `debuglevel` argument. The following target will cause the error.

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,source,vars" nowarn="true" />
```

Change it to:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,source" nowarn="true">
```

This is probably a JMockit bug - very subtle and annyoing to find out.

Comment: It worked! You're a life-saver! This was something I had given up on as "unfixable" :)

Answer (score 0):

I only saw this question today, but if you can, send me some tests that throw the ClassFormatError when running with EMMA, and I will try to find the bug in JMockit.

By the way, have you tried to use JMockit Coverage? Just add jmockit-coverage.jar to the classpath, and see what you get. Typically, this will produce (without any extra configuration) a nice HTML coverage report in the "coverage-report" dir under the working dir. It can't get any easier than that!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but this problem was on a project at work, and I don't think my company would be pleased with me sending you bits of the source. If I manage to make an example test that exhibits the problem, I'll let you know.

I haven't tried JMockit Coverage. I'll check it out! The main reason I use EMMA is that it has good plugins for both Eclipse and Hudson.

Comment: Hey Rogerio, let me see if I can get you a representative class to repro this.

Answer (score 0):

My team had the same issue. The concrete case was: using jMockit to mock static methods from a class in a unit-test suite running under TeamCity with EMMA as the coverage tool. The solution was the following:

Add a tear-down method to each test which mocked static methods:

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  Mockit.tearDownMocks(ClassWithStaticMethods.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update jmockit from 1.5 to any recent version.